# Delete cache from html page

Tags: javascript, html, caching

I'm building a html page with some js included. To view the content, you have to log in as a specific user. If you are not logged in, it should bring you to the login page. After logging out, when clicking on a menu item it should also redirect you to the login page.

My problem is: after logout, it will not redirect you to the login page for like 20-30 seconds, instead the content will load from cache.

I already tried to add these lines:

```
<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache,no-store,must-revalidate"/>
<meta http-equiv="expires" content="-1"/>
<meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache"/>
```

But it doesn't matter, the caching still goes on and on.
Do you have any idea what should I do to stop it?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What happens when you logout? For instance, are you clicking a "logout" link and going to a separate "/logout" page and then doing something like clicking the back button? How are you getting back to your page where it should show login? Or are you trying to control all this in JS/AJAX requests?

Comment: My javascript sends an AJAX request what is processed by the API(jersey based) which destroys the authentication token. After that it should redirect to the login page because there's no token but it only happens after like 20 seconds. Until that period, i can load any menus without beeing authenticated.

Comment: You will need to reload the page, or change the location when that AJAX response returns. This is less to do with the browser cache and moreso with the fact that you may have loaded many assets into the page's current state.

Answer (score 0):

> If you are setting the user id in the cookie , then on the logout.php you have to unset the cookie which contains the user id .
>   Also redirect it to loginPage as shown below :-

```
session_start();
session_unset($_SESSION['userId']);     
session_destroy();
header("Refresh: 0; URL=".BASE_PATH."php/LoginPage.php");
```

Comment: Its a Jersey rest api what is authenticated by apache shiro. So basically i have a simple html page which content is rendered by javascript. After logout i unset the authentication token in shiro(which is an intercepter) so it shouldn't display the page since im not authenticated to see. It prevents to access the javascript as its excepted, but i see the skeleteon of the html page so i assume it loads the html page from cache. I want to prevent this.

Comment: Sorry, i misswrote the last part. I meant to write:

...It prevents to access the json datas which is provided by the server...